# Check to see if a combination of bools exists in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have a multidimensional array of strings that looks similar to the following. The first column is the ID, column 2-4 are three different variables:

```
              #ID    Var1    Var2   Var3
comparison = [['1' 'False' 'False' 'True']
              ['2' 'False' 'True' 'False']
              ['3' 'False' 'True' 'False']
              ...
              ['98' 'False' 'True' 'False']
              ['99' 'False' 'True' 'False']
              ['100' 'False' 'True' 'False']]
```

I have a loops that prints out where all three variables are true, this works fine:

```py
true_vars = np.array([])

for idx in comparison:
    if ((idx[1] == 'True') and (idx[2] == 'True') and (idx[3] == 'True')):
        true_vars = np.append(true_vars, idx)
```

However I want to write another loop that checks if in the total array of 100 rows there are no ID's where all three variables are true. Something similar to the following although the following does not work:

```py
true_vars = np.array([])

for idx in comparison:
    if ((idx[1] == 'True') and (idx[2] == 'True') and (idx[3] == 'True')):
        true_vars = np.append(true_vars, idx)
    elif not exist ((idx[1] == 'True') and (idx[2] == 'True') and (idx[3] == 'True')):
        print('there are no true ID's in comparison')
```

So the ideal would be that it goes through all 100 rows in my comparison array, does not find any row where all 3 values are true and therefore prints out that in comparison there are no ID's where all 3 variables are true.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you not simply check if `true_vars` is empty at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.

```
import numpy as np

comparison = [['1', 'False', 'True', 'True'],
          ['2', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
          ['3', 'True', 'True', 'True'],
          ['100', 'False', 'True', 'False']]

true_vars = np.array([])

for idx in comparison:
  if ((idx[1] == 'True') and (idx[2] == 'True') and (idx[3] == 'True')):
    true_vars = np.append(true_vars, idx)
  if idx[0] == '100' and len(true_vars) == 0:
    print('there are no true ID\'s in comparison') 
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done without for loop using the [np.ndarray.all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html#numpy.ndarray.all) method:

```py
import numpy as np

comparison = np.array([['1', 'False', 'False', 'True'],
                       ['2', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
                       ['3', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
                       ...
                       ['98', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
                       ['99', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
                       ['100', 'False', 'True' ,'False']])

# Since you values are string we compare them with 'True' to get booleans:
(comparison[:,1:] == 'True').all(axis=1)
array([False, False, False,..., False, False, False])
```

Now if you want to check if any of this is true you can use [np.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```py
np.any((comparison[:,1:] == 'True').all(axis=1))
```